# viewForHeaderInSection alignment wrong (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have no idea where I'm wrong. The text is always aligned from the left .

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let sectionHeight:CGFloat = 40
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Helper.screenWidth, height: sectionHeight))
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(fromHex: "F7F7F7")
        headerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(fromHex: "F7F7F7").cgColor
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 15)
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        titleLabel.text = "Dummy test Dummy test"
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        titleLabel.sizeToFit()
        var frame = titleLabel.frame
        frame.origin.x = 15
        frame.origin.y = sectionHeight - frame.size.height - 7
        titleLabel.frame = frame
        headerView.addSubview(titleLabel)

        return headerView
```

[image]

PS : `screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width`

Comment: Have you tried titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter; ?

Comment: if you watch closely you can see it

Comment: If I look closesly I see a dot in NSTextAlignment.center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  this

```
 let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Helper.screenWidth, height: sectionHeight))

 headerView.addSubview(titleLabel)

 titleLabel.center = headerView.center
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()
```

The above line makes the frame of label according to its text length. (You can try to change the background color of label to see the label's width). Remove the above line and you will get the preferred text alignment.

Also set the frame of label as below:-

```
var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Helper.screenWidth, height: headerView.frame.size.height)
frame.origin.x = 15
frame.origin.y = sectionHeight - frame.size.height - 7
titleLabel.frame = frame
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `sizeToFit`, this will shrink/expand the label to match the size of the text, so any text alignment within this lable is obsolete.

I think you mean `titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`; this will now use a smaller font if (and ony if) the text is too large to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your text is center in your label, but your label is not centered in your view.
You resized your label to fit your text by calling `titleLabel.sizeToFit()`.

Try to do:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let sectionHeight:CGFloat = 40
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Helper.screenWidth, height: sectionHeight))
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(fromHex: "F7F7F7")
        headerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(fromHex: "F7F7F7").cgColor
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 15)
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        titleLabel.text = "Dummy test Dummy test"
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        titleLabel.sizeToFit()

        titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 15.0, y: sectionHeight - frame.size.height - 7, width: headerView.size.width - 15.0*2.0, height: titleLabel.size.height)

        headerView.addSubview(titleLabel)

        return headerView
}
```